# Range of Cells from sheet 1 copied to sheet 4 in different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am having problems coping cells from one sheet to another sheet. Error script out of range.  Seems so simple to do but is not working.  Any suggestions from the pros.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheet4.Select

'Copy the data
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D7").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G7").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A12").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A16").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A29").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet4").Activate
 'Select the target range
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A6").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("E6").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("H6").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("G8").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A10").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("G10").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A12").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A14").Paste
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A19").Paste
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False



End Sub
```

Comment: Try pastespecial. And if you don't need formatting, just set each range to each other. Also you want to copy paste each range, not copy all then paste all.

Comment: The script out of range occurs on the first line of sheet1 copy.

Comment: Possibly because your first line is to select sheet4? I don't know how select works because I avoid it at all cost XD Do you need formatting?

Comment: Are you sure there is a "Sheet4"? Try commenting out `Sheet4.Select` at the top. As @findwindow says, that shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: I believe I have found my issue.  There seems to be a problem with coping merged cells to other merged cells.  Can anyone comment on this. Ex. Cells(A1:C1) on sheet 1 to cells(F7:H7) on sheet 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need formatting, I'd do something like

```
Set ws1 = WorkSheets("Sheet1")
Set ws4 = WorkSheets("Sheet4")

With ws4
    .Range("A6").Value = ws1.Range("A7").Value
    .Range("E6").Value = ws1.Range("D7").Value
    .Range("H6").Value = ws1.Range("G7").Value
    .Range("G8").Value = ws1.Range("C10").Value
    .Range("A10").Value = ws1.Range("A12").Value
    .Range("G10").Value = ws1.Range("C12").Value
    .Range("A12").Value = ws1.Range("A14").Value
    .Range("A14").Value = ws1.Range("A16").Value
    .Range("A19").Value = ws1.Range("A29").Value
End With
```

Comment: I have tried this but get a "Script our of range" error.

Comment: Here is the code I have written:  
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws4 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

With ws4
    .Range("a6:b6").Value = ws1.Range("a7:b7")
    .Range("D6").Value = ws1.Range("c7")

End With
End Sub

Comment: Try adding `.value` where you dropped it. Edit: perhaps also add `thisworkbook.` before `worksheets()`

Comment: Hey fellow coders.  I admit that I am new to this whole vba thing, but  why does this produce a script out of range error: Dim ws1 as worksheet set ws1 = worksheet("sheet1").  I have use different variables and it worked.  Is there something in vba  that uses "ws1"

Comment: You dropped a "s". I would try `set ws1 = thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1")`